# I get an error "Not enough input arguments." in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, plot

```
function plot_normal_dist(mu, sigma)
  x = mu-3:0.01:mu+3;
  y = 1 / (sigma * sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-(x-mu).^2 / (2*sigma^2));
  plot(x, y)
  xlabel('x')
  ylabel('Probability density')
  title(['Normal Distribution: \mu = ' num2str(mu) ', \sigma = ' num2str(sigma)])
  
  subplot(1,3,1)
  plot_normal_dist(0, 1)
  subplot(1,3,2)
  plot_normal_dist(1, 2)
  subplot(1,3,3)
  plot_normal_dist(-1, 0.5)

end
```

I could'n figure it out why I get this error. It is about the mu values but I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Formatted as it is this function occurs in infinite recursion.
If we omit the second section, meaning that this is the function now:

```
  function plot_normal_dist(mu, sigma)
  x = mu-3:0.01:mu+3;
  y = 1 / (sigma * sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-(x-mu).^2 / (2*sigma^2));
  plot(x, y)
  xlabel('x')
  ylabel('Probability density')
  title(['Normal Distribution: \mu = ' num2str(mu) ', \sigma = ' num2str(sigma)])
  end
```

and we call it using the second section from command window:

```
 subplot(1,3,1)
 plot_normal_dist(0, 1)
 subplot(1,3,2)
 plot_normal_dist(1, 2)
 subplot(1,3,3)
 plot_normal_dist(-1, 0.5)
```

it work as intended encountering no errors.